# Pass a Variable to Reference as a Table Name in sqlQuery

Tags: sql, r

I have few tables, let's call them `{table_sql_1, table_sql_2, and table_sql_3}` in the database and I want to import them into R.

I'll be using,

```r
sqlQuery(con, "select * from table_sql_1"), 
sqlQuery(con, "select * from table_sql_2"),
sqlQuery(con, "select * from table_sql_3")
```

to call the tables, and the string  in common for these tables is "table_sql_" but that can change and I'd like to create a variable for it,

```r
x = "table_sql_" so that I can run queries like these:
```

```r
sqlQuery(con, "select * from $x_1"), 
sqlQuery(con, "select * from $x_2"),
sqlQuery(con, "select * from $x_3")
```

I was able to use the gsubfn library to do something similar but the variable reference is within the WHERE statement rather than the table name itself.

Answer (score 0):

Updated: This has been resolved using paste() to create the sql statements with variable x.